# solving ODE : $\ln y = y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Intuitively, I found a solution : $y=1$

But I wonder a general solution or some hints of this.

---

I tried :

Change ODE to exponential form : $y=e^{y'}$ and multiply $y'$ both side.

$yy'=y'e^{y'}$ and take $W(x)$ both side and I got $W(yy')=y'$.

So, $$y=\int W(y(x)y'(x))dx$$ and I stucked here.

Is this integratable? or is there an other approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

We replace $y'$ with $\frac{dy}{dx}$. The resulting ODE is seperable: $$\ln y= \frac{dy}{dx}\Rightarrow dx=\frac{dy}{\ln y} \Rightarrow \int 1\cdot dx=\int\frac{dy}{\ln y}$$ Sadly, $ \int\frac{dy}{\ln y}$ has no closed form but [it has its own special function $\operatorname{li}(y)$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) so the equation boils down to $x+C= \operatorname{li} (y)\Rightarrow y=\operatorname{li}^{-1}(x+C)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by separation of variables:\begin{align}\log y=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}&\iff\mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\log y}\\&\iff x=\operatorname{li}(y)+C,\end{align}where $\operatorname{li}$ is the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). So, $y(x)=\operatorname{li}^{-1}(x-C)$.